# How to assign a single-menu-template to a menu-items in a taxony/ cat/ subcat/ subcat-item

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, template-hierarchy

Hi hope really someone can assist.
I have created a single-meny-template with post-type-meny, and I have created taxonomy, categories, sub-categories and subcat-items.

What happens is that the templates gets assigned to /psk/meny instead of /psk/meny/cat/subcat/subcat-item.

//Single-meny-template with post-type-meny

```
 /*
 Template Name: Single Meny Template
 Template Post Type: meny
 */
```

This is my function hook the template.

```
custom_template_for_meny_items($template) {
    global $post;

    // Check if we have a valid post object
    if (is_a($post, 'WP_Post') && $post->post_type === 'meny') {
        // Check if the custom template exists in the theme
        $custom_template = locate_template('templates/single-meny-template.php');

        if (!empty($custom_template)) {
            return $custom_template;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'custom_template_for_meny_items');
```

Thank you for clearifying.